# Live update score on a PHP scoreboard for user

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want live score board screen in PHP. I have completed all on click button + or - score board is dynamically change score. But we need to refresh page look latest score. I want as we click + or - button to change score that score should be directly update score on screen for user without refreshing page.

How can I create a solution for this?

Comment: Use AJAX or websockets if you want to avoid refreshing the whole page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Voting to close as "needs focus".

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without having knowledge on how actually you have implemented your code, I can only give basic idea on this.

You need 3 files for this:

1. main.html: where the scoreboard is included.
2. scoreboard.php: where the scoreboard is shown.
3. updateSB.php: where the scoreboard is updated.

**main.html**

```
<div class="somediv">
  <div class="scoreboard" id="scoreboard">
  <!--This is the division I will load scoreboard dynamically-->
  </div>
</div>
<script>
 //Loading initial scoreboard here
 $('#scoreboard').load("scoreboard.php");
 //Now do ajax calls for '+' '-' buttons (onclick) here
 $.post("updateSB.php",{type : "plus/minus"},
 function(data, status){
   if(status=="success"){
     //Loading scoreboard for every update
     $('#scoreboard').load("scoreboard.php"); 
   }
 });
</script>
```

**scoreboard.php**

```
<div class="scoreboard">
  <div class="header">Some team <?echo $team1;?> vs team <?echo $team2?></div>
  <div class="body">
    some sort of table score here?
    Score :- <?echo $score;?>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**updateSB.php**

```
<?
//Here is where you update ur scoreboard
if(isset($_POST['type']){
  if($_POST['type']=="plus"){
  //Perform plus on score
  }
  elseif($_POST['type']=="minus"){
  //Perform minus on score
  }
}
?>
```

**Points to remember**

1. Use ajax in proper way ie, do right request and handle the request at backend correctly.
2. Implementation of dynamic scoreboard is possible if you are using some global variables or database at the backend.